# XSL How to concatenate text with xsl:number?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am very new to xsl and attempting to write a script to parse a xml message and call a template (which I do not have control over to format the input). Some of the fields in the XML message can appear multiple times; in these cases I want to append a number to the end of "StringValue" and pass it into the with-param="pet" of the call-template that specifies which occurrence it is.

The code below seems to do what I want; but XML Spy says it is invalid XML.  Is there a better way to append "StringValue" and "1", "StringValue" and "2", etc for each template match of "Dog/Color"?

For example:

```
<xsl:template match="Dog/Color">
    <xsl:call-template name="FormatContents">
            <xsl:with-param name="pet">StringValue<xsl:number level="any"/></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="color">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090271/xsl-how-to-concatenate-text-with-xslnumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment you gave is valid, are you sure the error came from that bit? It is always best to post complete examples.

Input:

```
<Dog>
<Color>Red</Color>
<Color>Green</Color>
</Dog>
```

XSLT 1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Dog/Color">
 <xsl:call-template name="FormatContents">
  <xsl:with-param name="pet">StringValue<xsl:number level="any"/></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="color">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FormatContents">
 <xsl:param name="pet"/>
 <xsl:param name="color"/>
 [<xsl:value-of select="$pet"/>][<xsl:value-of select="$color"/>]
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
 [StringValue1][Red]


 [StringValue2][Green]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response David; after going back and double checking I found that my error was coming from XMLSpy not seeing the call template.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is `position()` - i.e.:

```
<xsl:template match="Dog/Color"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="FormatContents"> 
     <xsl:with-param name="pet">StringValue<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:with-param> 
     <xsl:with-param name="color"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
     </xsl:with-param> 
  </xsl:call-template> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: position() would not (in general) give the same number as xsl:number level="any"